# How do I wait for asynchronous table writes on BigQuery before joining and exporting them to GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have a system running on Google Cloud Platform and it works as the following:

First, there is a Cloud Function that is triggered by a data upload on a specific bucket. It then organizes this data and generates processor jobs as ".json's", which are saved to another bucket.

There is a second Cloud Function - the core of the system - that is triggered by this ".json" upload. It then processes the data and writes the output results in a BigQuery dataset, as a single table.

I have also written another Cloud Function that joins all the tables within this BigQuery dataset and exports it to a CSV in a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Hence the problem arises: I can only call this last aggregating Cloud Function once all the tables are inserted in BigQuery. How do I manage this? How can I trigger this function only after all the tables are there?

Comment: Not easy answer. I just would like to have some details of your architecture: Why are you producing different JSON, handle them independently and then merging all the data in a same table? Is your load jobs have different schema? You can't load them in a single jobs? Other question: Do you know every time the number of JSONs and the number of load jobs that you will run each time? Or it's variable? Do you know the longest load job duration ?

Comment: I generate different JSON due to computational capabilities. A Cloud Function would not be able to handle the amount of data if it were to process everything needed in only one instance. Therefore I divide what has to be calculated and there are multiple instances of the cloud function processing the data in parallel. Yes, I know beforehand the amount of JSONs that are generated, and I also create a overview.json with summarizing information such as the number of jobs - but mind it could be tricky, since a function could fail and not create the table in BigQuery. The job duration is variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way, but I have 2 proposals for this

- If you aren't time constraint and if processing file sequentially is possible, you can do this

  - 1st function makes the split and build the `overview.json` file. Then call the 2nd function with in parameter, the name of the 1st json in the `overwien.json` file
  - The 2nd function process the data of the JSON file according with the parameter, write them to BQ. Then call the 2nd function with the next entry in the `overview.json` file. If it's the last entry, call the 3rd function
  - The 3rd function is called after all the data have been processed

It works, but you loose the power of parallelisation.

- The other solution is to use Datastore/Firestore. And to do this

  - The 1st function makes the split and write an entry in Datastore/Firestore with the list of JSON file to process and their status to "unprocessed".
  - The 2nd function is triggered on json upload (like today), process the data, write them to BigQuery, update the status on the JSON file in Datastore/Firestore as "processed", and call the 3rd functions
  - The 3rd function queries Datastore/Firestore and checks if all the json files to process are in status "processed". If no, exit the function. If yes, perform the processing in this function.

I prefer this solution. You have to take care of race condition on the last function (I can provide you tips to handle it if you want), and you need to have a global build ID for not mixing the status update of 2 different executions (if there is 2 concurrents execution of the 1st function)

**UPDATE**

For race condition, I usually perform this

- Create a space (table or collection) where to log something. In you case, it can be with the overview document in Firestore.
- The 3rd function, when it has checked that all the parts have been processed, check if 3rd function is running

  - If yes, exit
  - If no, write an unique ID, generated by the function (UUID for example), in the table/collection (in Firestore in your case)
- The 3rd read again the table/collection (in Firestore in your case) and check if the saved ID is its own ID

  - If yes, process
  - If not, exit

it's not perfect, but it can cover the most of cases.

Comment: I prefer the second solution too. I was also thinking about writing the status in a BigQuery table. What do you think about this, especially when comparing it with the Firestore solution? Any advantages/disadvantages? I would like tips on that (race condition), thanks! And about the global build ID, it's on the roadmap to develop an ID assignment functionality in the fist Cloud Function.

Comment: Bigquery is also a solution. All depends on what you want to do. Want to perform analysis and statistics on the processing duration of each part? Yes, BigQuery is the right place for analytics, agrations and statistics. But, if you don't need that, I strongly recommend Firestore: quicker and cheaper. For the race condition, I update my answer